# GnuPG: gpg cant be used inside a .bat

Tags: batch-file, gnupg

I'm writing a batch script, which has to encrypt a file with GnuPG (2.1.18) on Windows 10 (64Bit). I installed GnuPG with the installer that is available on the website.

When I open a new cmd window and type `gpg --version` the command is executed properly. After changing the directory, e.g. `C:\PGPTest\`, the command cannot be executed anymore. Cmd states that "The command 'gpg' is wrong or cannot be found'. Opening a new cmd in the directory allows me to run the gpg command. Running the batch file with a gpg command throws the error again.

I set the homedir for GnuPG in the registry. This changed nothing. What do I have to change, to be able to execute the gpg commands in any directory?

Comment: you have to add the homedirectory of the `gpg` command in your path first! [This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) may help you.

Comment: The homedirectory of `gpg` is listed in the path variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory in which `gpg.exe` is resident must be included in the `path`

```
set "path=whereveryourgpgdotexeislocated;%path%"
```

would set this for the current session ONLY

```
setx path "whereveryourgpgdotexeislocated;%path%"
```

would set it for all *future* `cmd` invocations, but bizarrely not for the current session.

Comment: I used the setx command and opened a new `cmd`. I'am still getting the error.

Comment: Okey I tried the first command. This didn't work. Logging off and rebooting the machine seemed to solved the problem. Thanks :)